# QGIS Extend Toolbar (GUI) Button Functionality via Python Plugin?

Tags: qgis, python

Is it possible to piggyback onto the QGIS split method via a python plugin?  Are toolbar buttons accessible via the python API?

This looks like [the class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a98164cb900555b00b58e913223ec5b8d) that I need to access.  Access ideas?

Proposed Workflow to Give an Implementation Example:

1. Initialize editing
2. Split the line as per [How to Split Features in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46862/how-to-split-features-in-qgis)
3. Launch a custom GUI or otherwise call a set of functions to start to build a list that I push to the DB table on saving edits.

Comment: `actionSplitFeatures` will help you run the split tool but after that it's not going to be much help.   So you want to show a UI after the split tool is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really change the behavior of the built in split tool, and I'm not sure it would be good in this case anyway. What you can do however is create your own split tool and call `QgsVectorLayer::splitFeatures` which will cut the features in the layer when you give it a line.

All of the split logic is done in this method and the built in tool really only handles drawing the line and calling this function.