# Creating centerline of river in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, centroids

I made two river bank lines and I want to associate them.

[image: Example_1]

I want to make a centerline using two rows as a base. I managed to make the centre line with a lot of work creating several lines from one margin to the other of the river and then using the centroid, but this solution is very tiring and I have to do this in several areas.

[image: Example_2]

Comment: I think after 6 years a new question is legit and answers provided are not up to date for version 3

Comment: Yeah, but this question als is 5 years old.

Comment: @Erik it was asked 3 days ago (2019-04-14)

Comment: Yeah, I thought April 14 = April 2014 -.-

Answer (score 18):

The surest method for solving your question from the point of view of the cartographic approach is to use the Voronoi Polygons.

I offer one of the solutions to your question using QGIS tools.

So, the initial data is a river as an areal object, see the figure below.
[image]

2) Vector > Geometry processing > Convert polygons into lines, see image below
[image]

3) Open the closed line QGIS "Split Features" tool and run the GRASS v.split tool, so that the points are evenly distributed along the line and run the Vector> Geometry Processing> Voronoi Polygons tool on them, see the figure below

[image]

or run the plugin with the name in the screenshot below, which is more convenient ...
[image]

4) Cut the original Voronoi polygons from the result with Vector > Geoprocessing > Trim and then select only one half of the river area, see the picture below using the Ctrl key and the selection tool [image] more
Vector > Geoprocessing > Merge by grounds ... > By all indications.

[image]

[image]

5) Cut from the source layer the result of the selected left or the right area, see the picture below.

[image]

6) Then from the result of cutting create a line, blow it up, remove unnecessary parts and leave the centre line of the river, see figure below
[image]

This is the main approach to solving your question and it is clear that a variety of tools allows you to solve your question in various ways, but the idea remains the same, good luck ...

Comment: This is a great solution. Have you been able to automate this in Python?

Comment: @Aaron, Unfortunately, I haven't studied Python yet, but I'm closer to Postgres/PostGIS :-)...

Comment: @Aaron, I implemented this technique in geoSQL (as I call PostGIS) and its result is different from the ST_StraightSkeleton and ST_ApproximateMedialAxis functions...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/347625/120129...

Answer (score 6):

The [HCMGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/HCMGIS/) says it does this:

> Spatial Processing: Create Skeleton/Medial Axis/ Centerline for road/ river networks and similar linear structures

Compatible with QGIS 3 and later; not compatible with QGIS 2.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that plugin, and perhaps mention the version(s) it works with?

Comment: Just tested with QGIS 3.14 (Windows 7)--takes a little time on a complex network, but works well.

Comment: Works really nice in v3.20. (use case: a single, linear polygon with moderately irregular boundary geometry)

Comment: I'll add that this only adresses part of the answer...trimming of the skeleton is still required (per Step 4 on in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318733/17482)

Comment: Be aware that there is a feature limit (100).

Answer (score 3):

Try the GRASS algorithm [`v.centerline`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/addons/v.centerline.html). You may have to tweak around with the parameters, but as long as your river polygons are longer than they are wide it should work for a large portion of your inputs.

Comment: Can you explain how to use it in QGIS?

Comment: @MrXsquared I am actually now surprised to find that this tool is not accessible from the Geoprocessing toolbox, so I guess my answer is not that appropriate to the question.