# Using Voronoi.Skeleton in QGIS

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen, skeleton

My purpose is to make a central line from a polygon.
For this I use the skeleton algorithm from a polygon, but I did not manage to get a line.

I draw the polygon.

[image]

I launch the program.

[image]

It doesn't work!

[image]

Comment: Please include the detailed information in a way than others can reproduce your steps and result.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318733/120129...Maybe this approach will help you...

Comment: Thanks Cyril M, your comment is the solution.

Comment: Always glad if my decision helps someone :-)...