# Merge two lines into one center line

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, line, merge

I want to merge two lines that their distance is from 0 meter to 20 meter. How can I do that by QGIS or ArcGIS ?
[image: Initial data]

[image: Distance between A and B lines are from 0 to 20 meters]

[image: Result that I would like to have]
The link for download data. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Y-cuqGPypva0Xz97LLKrxK8zPraXCDd/view?usp=sharing

---

the result when I use the Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline (Cartography Toobox)
[image: Before]

[image: After]
The result as you can see that 
(2) the 2 lines did not merge into 1
(1) the tool did nothing
Here, I would like to see that 2 lines should merge into 1.

Comment: Please decide which software you're going to use for this task, otherwise answering and/or finding the correct answer later on is harder.

Comment: Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline (Cartography Toobox)  requires advanced license https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/collapse-dual-lines-to-centerline.htm

Comment: In QGIS, how can I do this, please @Erik

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318733/120129

Comment: Thank you @CyrilMikhalchenko

Comment: It's something...:-)

Comment: It is preferable that you digitized new lines manually. It is not a huge layer. I downloaded rar file and visualized layer is multipart, with 226 single parts, with multiple self intersections and, possibly, with many topological and geometry issues. I tried it out simplify tool of Processing Tool Box and it can be obtained a better aspect of layer but, it is not the solution.

Comment: Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.