# Creating road center line from Grid-Polygon Shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have the shapefiles for the polygon part which are colored as yellow but there is no any specific shapefile for the white parts( roads).

Note: I have seen the same question here as below but it didn't work for me using Qgis 3.16.0 with grass 7.8.4.

- [Finding centrelines from polygons in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis)

and

- [Creating centerline of river in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318721/creating-centerline-of-river-in-qgis?newre)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "didnt work", you get error messages or what?

Comment: Dear BERA, it says, your shape file doesn't have well defined polygon to extract road center line. In short, the road polygon is empty rather there is a shape file for other Land use Polygon parts.

Comment: Create a polygon covering you entire shapefile, then use Difference to create the road polygons

Comment: Dear BERA, Thank you. I created the road edge lines by using Difference and I exploded these lines for my own road classification. The next question is, how to have the center line for these road edge lines?

Comment: And further in front of you lies a large stone pointer, which says: left you go - use Raven's polygons, right you go - use Triangulation Delaunay, forward you go - into a dark cave (a modified fragment of one folk tale). Where do you want to go? :-)...

Comment: And here's a hint, if you have geodata in the form of a grid, it's better to go to the right, if the geodata have a curved shape, it's better to go left, and sometimes there are all cases simultaneously...

Comment: Dear  Cyril Mikhalchenko, I am lucky that you are the one who answered the following question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318721/creating-centerline-of-river-in-qgis/318733#318733.

Comment: But, do me a favor! Do you think making more dense points in the straight lines will help me to get the perfect center line using the Voronoi Polygons?.

Comment: No Polygons Voronoy will give you a wavy line, which can be corrected with the help of centroids of the segments... If you have polygons in the form of a grid, I will add my answer...

Comment: Alright. I am waiting.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My test source data is a file called "poly_town", almost the same as in your picture, i.e. approximately a grid.

[image]

1. Extract vertices with the geo tool: `Vector>Processing geometry>Extract vertices`, see the figure below for the result.

[image]

2. Create combined buffers on the selected nodes using the geo tool: `Buffer` as shown in the figure below

[image]

See the figure below for the expected result.
[image]

3. Extract centroids on the combined buffer zones at the intersections of blocks, using the geoinstrument: `Vector>Processing of geometry>Centroids`, the result see the figure below

[image]

4. Perform Delaunay triangulation on these centroids, using: `Vector>Processing geometry>Triangulation Delaunay`, hereinafter

- convert polygons into lines with the geo tool: `Vector>Processing geometry>Convert polygons into lines`,
- then blow them up with: `Analysis Tools>Vector Geometry>Blow up Lines`, see the figure below

[image]

5. Select the required blasted lines that do not fall into quarters using the geo tool: `Analysis tools>Vector selection>Extract by spatial position` see the figure below
   [image]
6. Delete unnecessary artifacts and save the result as a new file using `<Export>-<Save objects as...` >...

see the figure below

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you, Cyril Mikhalchenko

Comment: Dear  Cyril Mikhalchenko, I checked it. But, I got some errors related to vertices generation for the lines which have had vertices at the middle,  besides to edge corner vertices. One thing, i say for sure is, the method you told me is perfect for case of grid vertices which has only one vertices at corner of each block.

Comment: Cherry on the cake of this method is that you must first create additional corresponding points on the opposite sides of your neighborhoods if there are none... i.e. there must be 2 points on each side (1+1) or 4 (2+2)....

Comment: Would you tell me the method to create additional corresponding points for all of unforeseen situations? is it by making denser points?

Comment: So far, from the QGIS geoinstrument set, the most optimal solution is the "Transects" geoinstrument on blasted lines, which makes it possible to lengthen them by a certain distance...