Create centerline of polygon in QGIS
I have building wall layer, and I want to extract the center line for generate the line of wall, as shown below, left is the origin polygons(complex multiple polygon with holes), red lines in the right is what I expected.

And I tried to use the Skeleton tool from HCMGIS. This is what I get:

Note that the line is not along the center of the wall, which means is not straight enough. Also there are redundant vertex in the red square.
I wonder if there is an alternative solution since I think skeleton may not meet my requirement:
1 skeleton calculate is slow.
2 Most segments in my polygon are symmetrical.
Any idea?

The segments may become more centered if you Densify the polygons

After densify the layer with 10, and then skeketon the densified layer, thing does not change more: https://i.imgur.com/B1zxdWq.png

Idea - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/377773/120129

@CyrilMikhalchenko: Thanks, I take a look at your link, it is amazing! .However in my case it can be used to for generate wall lines (with polyline data type) from rooms with gap(polygon data type). While what I need is generating wall lines from wall polygons.

@CyrilMikhalchenko: I tried the solution from your link,however in some case there should be four vertex to make the line center in the gap between the polygons, for example: https://i.imgur.com/k4w5hMd.png. I am thinking if it is possible to add the vertex by some algorithm?

Be sure to pay attention to the comments, the transects on the lines will help you get the points you need on opposite sides of the line...
