# Creating centrelines in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to create a centreline in QGIS from two other lines (such as a river bank) which won't always be equally apart?

I am aware that in ArcGIS Desktop there is Collapse Dual Line to Centerline which sounds like it is what is needed, but I have not found an equivalent in QGIS.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318733/120129...maybe this approach will solve your problem...